# Can I Write Propositional Logic Statement Using Functions Returning T/F?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

A pattern is a sequence of elements.

Let P, and P' are patterns.

I defined 'equality' and 'generality' as:

$$\def\false{\operatorname{false}}\begin{align}
 \operatorname {EqualTo}(P, P') ~&:=~\begin{cases}\false &:& \lvert P\rvert \neq \lvert P'\rvert \\[1ex]\bigwedge\limits_{i-1}^{\lvert P\rvert}\big(P_i=P_i'\big) &:& \lvert P\rvert = \lvert P'\rvert\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
 \operatorname {GeneralThan}(P, P') ~&:=~\begin{cases}
\false &:& \lvert P\rvert \neq \lvert P'\rvert \\[1ex]
\false &:& \sum_{i=1}^{\lvert P\rvert}\big[P_i \neq P_i'\big]=0 \\[1ex]\bigwedge\limits_{i-1}^{\lvert P\rvert}\big(P_i=P_i'\vee \underline{\;}\big) &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Then, can I write a propositional logic statement using the two functions like:

$$\operatorname{MatchedWith} \impliedby \operatorname{EqualTo}(P,P')\vee\operatorname{GeneralThan}(P,P')$$

Is it possible?

Or, should I make 'MatchedWith' as a predicate (by using equalit sign instead of implication sign)?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the underscore symbol in "GeneralThan" meant to indicate?

Comment: What is a pattern, what does $P_i$ mean? What does $\left[P_i\ne P'_i\right]$ mean? Is all this standard terminology?

Comment: @skyking Pattern is a sequence of elements. If all elements in a sequence are equal to corresponding elements in another sequence, they are equal.   A B C = A B C. But A _ C is more general than A B C. That's what I want to say. In a sequence A B C, P_1=A, P_2=B and P_3=C.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That's like wildcard? underscore can be matched with any symbol. A B C can be matched by both A B C, A _ C.

Comment: @skyking If you mean brackets, It is Iverson bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use $MatchedWith(P,P')$ since you want to define this predicate relative to patterns $P$ and $P'$.